# find elements in lists using For Loop

Tags: python-3.x

```
keys = ['a','H','c','D','m','l']
values = ['a','c','H','D']
category = []
for index, i in enumerate(keys):
for j in values:
    if j in i:
        category.append(j)
        break
    if index == len(category):
        category.append("other")
```

print(category)

My expected output is ['a', 'H', 'c', 'D', 'other', 'other']

But i am getting ['a', 'other', 'H', 'c', 'D', 'other']

Comment: You break out of the outer loop?

Comment: Looks like your indentation is off by a few spaces, is that how it is in your code? Also, try simply printing the condition (`print(m)`,`print(len(y))` and `print(m<len(y))`) to see what it evaluates to, that might give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: because you use keyword=`break` to ternimate outter loop directly, it causes never run inner loop. check this: [python break](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html)

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code. please dont consider space. the spaces are correct in code...

Comment: @Vivek, the space is very import for python.... becase of [python indent](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html)

Comment: @Sphinx: I tried without 'break' the i keeps on running infinitely

Comment: @Vivek, you should use `if condition: break`

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#4)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Aleksei I tried the code which you posted earlier it worked but you have edited it later...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: OP edited his question multiple times.

[Python documentation break statement:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break)

> It terminates the nearest enclosing loop.

You break out of the outer loop using the "break" statement. The execution never even reaches the inner while loop.

Now.. To solve your problem of categorising strings:

```
xs = ['Am sleeping', 'He is walking','John is eating']
ys = ['walking','eating','sleeping']
categories = []

for x in xs:
    for y in ys:
        if y in x:
            categories.append(y)
            break

    categories.append("other")

print(categories) # ['sleeping', 'walking', 'eating']
```

Iterate over both lists and check if any categories match. If they do append to the categories list and continue with the next string to categorise. If didn't find any matching category (defined by the count of matched categories being less than the current index (index is 0 based, so they are shifted by 1, which means == is less than in this case) then categorise as "other.

Comment: I tried removing break statement too. and added a print print(i) to test it. the outerloop, that is value of i started running infinitely.

Comment: @Vivek, its hard to tell you what to do exactly, when we do not know what the end goal is. But I guess you want to break out of the loop at some point, based on some condition. Eg. If CONDITION == True: break

Comment: i have edited my question. Now you can figure out my expected output

Comment: It worked fine, Thank you. but could you please explain me the logic of,' for index, i in enumerate(x):' why 'for index'

Comment: @Vivek I used the "index" to keep track if there was a match or not, but not that i think of it, its redundant. I will update it in a moment.